# Filter product Price and sort Asc Desc PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, filtering

i hope you alway care !
i was ask :

1. If i filter Product By form price MIN to MAX, can view already OK
2. after step filter (No. 1) and than filter ASC, DESC condition why my view page is "  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  " , why this it ???

.

```
<?php 
    include("config.php");
    $all_brand=$db->query("SELECT distinct brand FROM `products` WHERE category_id = '1' GROUP BY brand");
    // Filter query
    $sql= "SELECT distinct * FROM `products` WHERE category_id = '1'";

    if(isset($_GET['brand']) && $_GET['brand']!="") :
        $sql.=" AND brand IN ('".implode("','",$_GET['brand'])."')";
    endif;

    if(isset($_GET['sort_price']) && $_GET['sort_price']!="") :
        if($_GET['sort_price']=='price-asc-rank') :
            $sql.=" ORDER BY price ASC";
        elseif($_GET['sort_price']=='price-desc-rank') :
            $sql.=" ORDER BY price DESC";
        endif;
    endif;

    // filter by input price
    if(isset($_GET['min']) && $_GET['min']!="") :
     $sql.="AND price >= '".$_GET['min']."' ";
    endif;

    if(isset($_GET['max']) && $_GET['max']!="") :
     $sql.="AND price <= '".$_GET['max']."' ";
    endif;

    $all_product=$db->query($sql);
    ?>
```

**and my form :**

```
    *******filter ASC and DESC **********
<div class="panel list">                  
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <select name="sort_price" class="sort_rang" id="sort">
                                 <option value="">Paling baru</option>
                      <option <?=(isset($_GET['sort_price'])&&($_GET['sort_price']=='price-asc-rank')? 'selected="selected"' : '' )?>  value="price-asc-rank">Harga:Rendah ke tinggi </option>

                      <option <?=(isset($_GET['sort_price'])&&($_GET['sort_price']=='price-desc-rank') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' )?>  value="price-desc-rank">Harga:Tinggi ke rendah</option>
                            </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

    <!-- filter price -->
                        <div class="sidebar-row">
                        <h4>RENTANG HARGA</h4>
                              <input type="text" name="min" id="min" placeholder=" Mulai dari harga" onkeypress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['min']) ? $_GET['min'] : ''; ?>"> <br>
                                <br>
                              <input type="text" name="max" id="max" placeholder=" Sampai dgn harga" onkeypress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['max']) ? $_GET['max'] : ''; ?>"> <br>
                                <br>
                              <input type="submit" class="sort_rang" value="Tampilkan">
                        </div>
```

Comment: You are putting an and after the order by which will be causing your error. The order by needs to be last and group by second to last. Where's and ands come before.

Comment: Oke bro.. you has top solution. thank before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put your price `WHERE` after the `ORDER` :

```
include("config.php");
$all_brand=$db->query("SELECT distinct brand FROM `products` WHERE category_id = '1' GROUP BY brand");
// Filter query
$sql= "SELECT distinct * FROM `products` WHERE category_id = '1'";

if(isset($_GET['brand']) && $_GET['brand']!="")
    $sql.=" AND brand IN ('".implode("','",$_GET['brand'])."')";

// filter by input price
if(isset($_GET['min']) && $_GET['min']!="")
    $sql.="AND price >= '".$_GET['min']."' ";

if(isset($_GET['max']) && $_GET['max']!="")
    $sql.="AND price <= '".$_GET['max']."' ";

if(isset($_GET['sort_price']) && $_GET['sort_price']!="") :
    if($_GET['sort_price']=='price-asc-rank')
        $sql.=" ORDER BY price ASC";
    elseif($_GET['sort_price']=='price-desc-rank')
        $sql.=" ORDER BY price DESC";
endif;


$all_product=$db->query($sql);
```

**BTW : your code is SQL-Injection vulnerable. This is BAD, learn more : http://bobby-tables.com/php**

Comment: Yea bro...it great solutution, thank before it..
but i think more problem. 
problem is :
if cart order (first) is oke, but if action pagination after e.g in pag. 2 or 3 or 4 and add order , the order not responding . why ?